# I need an escape sequence for a '/' in a variable name used by a layerGroup in leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, leaflet, escaping

I'm creating a layerGroup list of markers from a MySQL DB using Ajax. It builds the list just fine but when I try to use the list in a leaflet map it errors.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: F is not defined

and points to the 'N0SAX/F' as the issue. I believe the issue is with the slash '/'.

```
var Stations = L.layerGroup([<?php echo ("$callsignList")?>]);
```

which is generated by PHP as:

```
var Stations = L.layerGroup([KA0OTL,W0WTS,AK0SK,K4PAT,WU0G,AD0TU,N0SAX,N0SAX/F,KD0ETL,K0KEX,WA0TJT,KM0EOC,AE0DP,KD0FIW,KE0LUA,K0OG]);
```

I've tried to escape the '/' in multiple ways but it is part of the value so it must remain in the name for the list to function properly as a layerGroup.

Escaping in MySQL didn't help, nor did it work when I tried it PHP while creating the list.

How can I tell leaflet to allow a '/' slash in a layerGroup definition?

Answer (score 0):

The value needs to be in quotes so it will be treated as a string, not JavaScript variables.

`json_encode()` will convert a PHP value to the corresponding JavaScript literal syntax.

```
var Stations = L.layerGroup([<?php echo json_encode($callsignList)?>]);
```

Comment: I thought that would do it but now i'm getting; leaflet.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_leaflet_id' on string

Comment: Can you show how you would call this function if you weren't generating the argument from PHP?

Comment: var Stations = L.layerGroup([KA0OTL,W0WTS,AK0SK,K4PAT,WU0G,AD0TU,N0SAX,N0SAX/F,KD0ETL,K0KEX,WA0TJT,KM0EOC,AE0DP,KD0FIW,KE0LUA,K0OG]);

Comment: That can't be right. The array elements need to be strings, otherwise it will try to use them as variables, and `N0SAX/F` will try to do division of two variables.

Comment: What is the value of `$callsignList`. It should be a PHP array of strings, and `json_encode()` will convert that to a JavaScript array of strings.

Comment: Glad your sticking with me. Here is a link to the source saved into a stand alone. https://net-control.us/play4.html. Truth be told I'm over my head.

Comment: So those are JavaScript variables that are set earlier in the script. How do they related to the PHP variable `$callsignList`? JavaScript variables can't have `/` in them, why are you producing variables like that?

Comment: For instance, the script has `var NARESEOC = new L.marker(...)`.

Comment: I'm a little confused, none of the javascript or PHP variables have a slash (/) in them. But you're right that might be the crux of the problem. Maybe we can chat during the day Friday, I'll look for a solution till then.

Comment: Examine how you're setting `$callsignList`.

Comment: Turns out... you were right, there are variables in Javascript being set by PHP that include a /. They are in the DB so of course they come out  of the DB that way. I can easily REPLACE() them in the MySQL code, lets say delete the / but it needs to be replaced by something, or at the least the 'F' in this case needs to be moved over so the value becomes N0SAXF but how? Thats what i'm working on now. Look again at the link I sent, it now works by going into the source and fixing the offending variables.

Answer (score 0):

The basic thing is `L.layerGroup` is a array of strings, so @Barmar is right.

```js
var Stations = L.layerGroup(["KA0OTL", "W0WTS", "AK0SK", "K4PAT", "WU0G", "AD0TU", "N0SAX", "N0SAX/F", "KD0ETL", "K0KEX", "WA0TJT", "KM0EOC", "AE0DP", "KD0FIW", "KE0LUA", "K0OG"]);
```

If it's an array of strings, it doesn't matter what will be there :)

**First option:**

Such things should be corrected at source. If this is a data error, it should be repaired in the database, if this cannot be done when extracting data select + relpace.
Something like that.

```sql
SELECT
   pub_city,
   country,
   REPLACE (country, '/F', '')
FROM publisher
```

**Second option:**

In php, `json_encode` should do the trick, and if you can't use `str_replace`

**Third option:**

On the js side, you can rewrite the table or remove `/F`.

```js
let tests = ["KA0OTL", "W0WTS", "AK0SK", "K4PAT", "WU0G", "AD0TU", "N0SAX", "N0SAX/F", "KD0ETL", "K0KEX", "WA0TJT", "KM0EOC", "AE0DP", "KD0FIW", "KE0LUA", "K0OG"];

tests.map(test => test.replace(/\/F/g, ''));
```

Good luck ;)